# Displaying whole ORACLE 8-bit CHARSETS in UNICODE

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, globalization

I maintain an Java EE web application against an eight bits charset oracle database.

The application will be used from abroad and I want to be able to check strings -for example with UNICODE regexps, and both from Java and from Javascript- to see if they fit into the database CHARSET.

One function in GDK -globalization developer kit- gives the equivalent Java name of the oracle charset -I think it was ISO-8859-15-. But I'm not certain the correspondence will be exact.

What I wanted is to display the whole charset -NOT ISO..., but the ORACLE one- char by char to use both from Java and Javascript, even to display the UNICODE points and to tell apart the control characters from printable ones.

There is a funcion in Oracle's GDK to that end?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found it! (Eureka!)

A little JAVA JDBC program resulted in exactly the characters in ISO-8859-15 that are distintc to ISO-8859-1 (by the way, I've learned that ISO-8859-1 occupies from 0x00 to 0xff in UNICODE).

Program output:

CHR: 164        UNICODE: 8364 euro sign

CHR: 166        UNICODE: 352

CHR: 168        UNICODE: 353

CHR: 180        UNICODE: 381

CHR: 184        UNICODE: 382

CHR: 188        UNICODE: 338

CHR: 189        UNICODE: 339

CHR: 190        UNICODE: 376

Program code (not using GDK at all):

NOTE: the statement "SELECT CHR(i using nchar_cs) FROM DUAL" just gave back the same numbers... WHY?

```
  for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
  {
    Statement select = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet result = select.executeQuery("select CHR(" + i +") from DUAL");
    while(result.next())
    {
      int unicodePoint = result.getString(1).codePointBefore(1);
      //int unicodePoint = result.getString(1).codePointAt(0);
      if (unicodePoint != i)
        System.out.println("CHR: " + i + "\tUNICODE: " + unicodePoint);
    }
    result.close();
    result = null;
    select.close();
    select = null;
  }
```